# How to allow two navigation bars in iphone to overlap?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I am designing a mobile application on iPhone. The problem that I'm having is that I have two navigation bars on the top and I want them to overlap.

Can anyone share with me a possible way of doing it.

Please check the design idea below.

[image: Double navigation bar]

Answer (score 1):

There is no posible by standard methods. You must make your custom navigation bars.
It can be just UIView with UIImage (like background) and with UIButton objects on UIImage.
For example, you make your CustomNavBar class, which is subclass of UIView, import it in your root view conreoller and write in viewDidLoad:

```
CustomNavBar *bar1=[CustomNavBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,25)];
UIImage *background1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 10);

 [bar1 addSubview:background1];
 [bar1 addSubview:button];
```

Comment: but will that work if the user interface function this way, please have a look at the images

Comment: Of course, you can do with bars, all, what you need.
How to do this animation, ask in other question.

Comment: do you mean that i have to animate the navigation bar going up? note that there will be more than one bar and the user has to be able to shift up and down the bars (you shift up and down the pages that you want to view), plus the user will have his account menu in the upper bar. what happened with me is that the whole application became unstable, and the lower bar does not fit perfectly within the upper bar.

Comment: There is no deference

Comment: Is it was helpful for you?

Comment: we're still having some problems :'( . ok now we have only one navigation bar, but what we're having a problem with is the second navigation is going all the way up, and we only want it to fit in the same position as the image